# Find the orthogonal projection of y onto subspace of $R^3$ spanned by S, where S is not orthogonal.

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, orthogonality, orthogonal-matrices

y and S are defined below:

$$y=
    \begin{bmatrix}
    9 \\
    2 \\
    -4 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

$$S=\{
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    0 \\
    1 \\
    \end{bmatrix},
    \begin{bmatrix}
    0 \\
    1 \\
    1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
    \}
$$

My first step would be to make the subspace S orthogonal via Gram-smith process:

$$ v_1 = s_1$$

$$ v_2 = s_2 - \frac{s_2 \cdot v_1}{v_1 \cdot v_1}v_1$$

and then use the formula:

$$ \hat y = \frac{y \cdot v_1}{v_1 \cdot v_1}v_1 + \frac{y \cdot v_2}{v_2 \cdot v_2}v_2$$

I end up with:

$$V=\{
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    0 \\
    1 \\
    \end{bmatrix},
    \begin{bmatrix}
    -\frac{1}{2} \\
    1 \\
    \frac{1}{2} \\
    \end{bmatrix}
    \}
$$

As orthogonal basis.

And use the formula $ \hat y $ to end up with:
$$\hat y =
    \begin{bmatrix}
    4 \\
    -3 \\
    1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

1. Is this the correct way to approach this?
2. Is there an easier way to approach this?

Comment: How is $S$ a subspace?

Comment: I modified the question; now in the questionheader its stated that the subspace of $R^3$ is spanned by S.

Comment: You mean $$ S= \operatorname{span} \left(\left\{ \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \right\} \right)$$

Comment: And $V$ is not a orthogonal matrix, again, you mean $$\left\{ \begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} -1/2 \\ 1 \\ 1/2 \end{pmatrix} \right\}$$ is a orthogonal $\textbf{basis}$ for $S$.

Comment: From then on, everything is correct, it's just a matter of ordering your work.

Comment: Thanks for your insight! Very happy with the feedback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is fine.

Alternatively, you can find a vector perpendicular to $S$. For example, $$p=\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\-1\end{pmatrix}$$ is perpendicular to both of the generators of $S$. Then you get:

$$\hat y = y-\frac{y\cdot p}{p\cdot p}=
    \begin{pmatrix}
    9 \\
    2 \\
    -4 \\
    \end{pmatrix} -5\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\-1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}4\\-3\\1\end{pmatrix}$$
which is the same as your answer.

In this case, finding $p$ might be easier since there is only one vector perpendicular to $S$ and it was easy to find.

More generally, you'd have to find a set of pairwise orthogonal $p_1,p_2,\dots,p_{n-k}$ which generate the space orthogonal to the $k$-dimensional subspace $S.$ That won't be easier than finding a basis for $S$ unless $k$ is close to $n.$

Comment: Nice addition, thanks! This is based on the fact that the orthogonal complement of y and the projection of y on the basis $S$ together make y, correct?

Comment: That is correct, @ReinierKoops